# Do we use "would rather" for past tense?

Tags: past-tense, would-rather

"I would rather go swimming with dad"
Does the sentence above refer to the past? If not, how can I rephrase it so that it does?

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a time period if you want it to take place in the past:

> When I was a child, I would always rather go swimming with Mom than with Dad.